# Загрузка аватара пользователем

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы $id пользователя определялся автоматически, и не надо было бы указывать $userid=5 (допустим) вручную, чтобы аватар загружал именно тот пользователь, который авторизован в своем аккаунте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно в скрипт загрузки аватара допускают только авторизованных пользователей. ПОэтому вас надо найти место, где происходит авторизация (там, как правило, есть что-то вроде "`if ($user = mysql_fetch_object($auth_query)) $authorized = true;`"), и установить в сессию значение идентификатора.

то есть:

```
session_start();
/* много кода */
// if ($user = mysql_fetch_object($auth_query))
//   $authorized = true;
if ($user = mysql_fetch_object($auth_query)) {
  $_SESSION['userID'] = $user->id;
  $authorized = true;
  }
```

И в скрипте загрузки аватара использовать `$_SESSION['userID']` вместо `$userID`.

ЗЫ: Тогда и для проверки авторизации в любом скрипте должна быть строка `session_start();` и можно делать так: `if (empty($_SESSION['userID'])) die('Вы не авторизованы');`

Answer (score 2):

Ну чаще всего в таких случаях авторизованному пользователю устанавливают COOKIE с необходимыми значениями например

при авторизации пользователя

```
if (auth($user_login, $user_password)) //авторизация пользователя
{
   set_cookie('id', $user_id);
   set_cookie('auth', md5($user_login.$user_password));
}
```

А дальше если пользователь авторизован то мы можем использовать переменную $_COOKIE['id']

Comment: Идея не очень, ибо установив полученные id и auth вы получите доступ к аккаунту пользователя...md5 пользователю без соли стоит передавать только в крайних случаях

Comment: auth не обязательно должен быть md5 от суммы $login.$password... его можно на сессию сгенерив из переменных окружения.

Comment: Его !нужно! генерировать из переменных окружения, отвечающих за клиента, браузер, ИП. И проверять тоже желательно.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказано выше авторизация обязательна, можно предложить и такой вариант:

```
$user=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(...)); /* получаем массив из базы по логину или что там у вас...*/
$_SESSION['id']=$user['id'];
// можно и кукисы вбить
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && mysql_result(mysql_query(..#1..),0)==1)
 {
   $user=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(..#1..));
 }
/*где #1 - проверка через сессию $_SESSION['id'] */
```

в итоге: $user['id'] - вставляете куда нужно....